# Creating a stoppable Linux Service

Tags: node.js, linux, service

I'm trying to run a NodeJS application as a Linux service. I created a service file under the `/etc/init.d` folder with the content below:

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80
# description: Description comes here....

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

start() {
    # code to start app comes here
    # example: daemon program_name &
    /usr/bin/node /home/folder/nodeapp.js &
    echo "Service started">&2
}

stop() {
    # code to stop app comes here
    # example: killproc program_name
    killproc /usr/bin/node
    echo "Service stopped">&2
}
case "$1" in
    start)
       start
       ;;
    stop)
       stop
       ;;
    restart)
       stop
       start
       ;;
    status)
       # code to check status of app comes here
       # example: status program_name
       ;;
    *)
       echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac
```

This is the JS file it runs:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end("aa1");
}).listen(8081);
```

I can start the service and it is working great. The problem is I don't know how to stop it properly. The stop function above actually kills the node process (node.exe) so all node applications are automatically stopped. I only need to stop the my nodeapp.js.

So I need something like that:

```
stop() {
    # code to stop app comes here
    # example: killproc program_name
    killproc /usr/bin/node /home/folder/nodeapp.js
    echo "Service stopped">&2
}
```

But of course, it isn't working.

By the way, please do not recommend to use systemctl or something new like it. I know it's easier but I have to use an older version of CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

The classic way of doing this is to write the process ID number out to a file directly after starting it (`echo $! > /var/run/myapp.pid`). To stop it, read the file back in and `kill` the PID.